# Case fans not all spinning at same speed?

Tags: motherboard, fan

I have 4 LED case fans installed. All of them are connected to sys_fan headers 1 - 4. But one of the fans has a much lower RPM than the others and it's LED's are dim. It's like it's not getting enough power or something. I know it's not the fan because i can plug it into the pump_fan header and it works fine. My motherboards software tells allows me to set the fans to smart mode and manual mode. And on manual mode i can bring the fan up to 75% speed and makes the LED's come on but it's not ideal because running it at 75% makes it kinda noisy. I know fan controllers exist and can probably fix this problem but i'm wondering if it's possible to "daisy chain" the fans together someway? Maybe it's a bad fan header?

Comment: Typically motherboards have a maximum amount of power they can supply to fans, it sounds like, that is the case here.  Those fan headers are likely all connected to the same power, so I don't believe, daisy chaining them would solve your issue.  There are fan controllers that might solve the problem, but only due to, the additional power you would have to provide it.

Comment: I don't think power is the problem as i can manually crank all of them up to 100% via the MSI software and they will all run wide open with LED's glowing.

Comment: Using a multimeter to measure the voltage and current across the terminals would help very much. The leds might be overloading your fan's source power supply. Did you try swapping out the fans?

Comment: I haven't yet tried swapping fans but i really really don't think it's the fan. I winder if i could daisy chain the molex cables to my PSU and just run them directly from that? Or would that just cause them all to run at 100%?

Comment: I think i might have figured out what's going on. My fans are 3 pin in DC mode. So in order for the board to control the fan speed correctly they need to be 4 pin PWM mode. I guess i will have to buy an adapter or a 4 pin molex cable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i finally got all the fans to spin at the same speed. I just deleted the MSI command center app and set the fan speed manually in the bios. Setting them all to about 700 RPM seems like a nice speed. Not too loud and seems to keep everything quiet.